# How do you animate an ant swarm?

Tags: animation

I wanted to ask how to make such an animation as in this gif:

[image: ants run downhill]

The video shows hundreds of creatures (ants?) swarming over the top of a hill and down the face.

How would you create such a swarm in Blender?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Check boids' tutorials:
[start from official guide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/physics/boids.html)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40657/2952) will address your question. Good luck, and welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!