# shrinkwrap modifier does not correctly snap a bezier curve to a surface

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, path, shrinkwrap

I want to animate a car driving over a desert landscape. I want to animate the car along a path (constraint/follow path). in order to snap that path to the landscape, I subdivided the path (30 times) and applied a shrinkwrap modifier. The shrinkwrap is kind of doing its thing but it leaves a gap between two of the dunes. Why is it doing this and how can I solve it? Here is the File: [image]

[image: Shrinkwrap]

Comment: Pls show us your setup with shrinkwrap and why this doesn't work (because it should)

Comment: @Chris hi, there! I tried it again and applied the rotation and position of the path. Now it seems to work but still the shrinkwrap ignores a part of the target mesh. I edited the question and added the Blend file.

Comment: unfortunately your link does not work

Comment: ah ok... now it should work :)

Comment: Easiest way is to draw the Bezier path across your landscape. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PWGCWIG_Sk) YT video. Although it's for Blender 2.81 it still applies to the current version.

Comment: My first thought is that maybe you need to enable Shrinkwrap snapping *only for the Z axis*. Limiting to Z should prevent curve points from clustering around peaks, and instead go straight down until they hit the terrain. Also, you might want to check out this [related answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40657/2952).

Comment: @JohnEason oh wow that‘s really useful!

Comment: @Mentalist i think for my case i’ll go for the curve solution, because i also want the cars to jump. but the march thing with the emitter is a really beautiful method!